# MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server versi

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to insert data into a MySQL table using my Flask app as shown below;

```
#Create MySQL connection and write data into the table user_data from the POST form
    sql_cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    
    sql_cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO user_data (make,model,trim,fuel_type,transmission,condition,body_type,region,descriptn,eng_capacity,year,mileage, estm_value)
        VALUES (new_info['make'],new_info['model'],new_info['trim'],new_info['fuel_type'],new_info['transmission'],new_info['condition'],
        add_bodytype['body_type'],add_region['region'],new_data['description'],new_data['eng_capacity'],year,new_data['mileage'], estm_value);""")
        
    mysql.connection.commit()
    sql_cursor.close()
```

This does not work too:

```
    sql_cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    
    sql_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO user_data (make,model,trim,fuel_type,transmission,condition,body_type,region,descriptn,eng_capacity,year,mileage, estm_value) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (new_info['make'],new_info['model'],new_info['trim'],new_info['fuel_type'],new_info['transmission'],new_info['condition'],add_bodytype['body_type'],add_region['region'],new_data['description'],new_data['eng_capacity'],year,new_data['mileage'], estm_value))
        
    mysql.connection.commit()
    sql_cursor.close()
```

I get the below error:

```
I get the below error:

MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition,body_type,region,descriptn,eng_capacity,year,mileage, estm_value)\n ' at line 1")
```

Someone please help me.

Comment: You can't put Python code into a string like that. Look at how to use placeholders.

Comment: Condition is a reserved word

Answer (score 2):

The homepage explains how to use placeholders https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html

If your variables are all valid.

this should work

```
sql_cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO user_data (make,model,trim,fuel_type,transmission,condition,body_type,region,descriptn,eng_capacity,year,mileage, estm_value)"""\
                """ VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s);""",(new_info['make'],new_info['model'],new_info['trim'],new_info['fuel_type'],new_info['transmission'],new_info['condition'],
    add_bodytype['body_type'],add_region['region'],new_data['description'],new_data['eng_capacity'],year,new_data['mileage'], estm_valu)))
    
mysql.connection.commit()
sql_cursor.close()
```

Comment: Hi nbk. Imagine its still throwing the same error.

Comment: you error code shows that you have  a \n, `estm_value)\n ` try to make it like it ios decribed here https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-long-string/ i also added some backslash,around some columns that looked like reserved words

Comment: MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition,body_type,region,descriptn,eng_capacity,year,mileage, estm_value) VALU' at line 1") . This is the error when I remove new lines

Comment: that is niot the corrected code i poosted please check again please

Comment: Whao. your code is attempting to write some lines halfway. Seems like you included some spaces on the column names? It seems to be working

Comment: MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' ' VALUES ('Toyota','Belta',' ','Petrol','Automatic','Locally u' at line 1") This is the new error. You can see its attempting to write

Comment: good, i chnged in my edited answer the single quotes with the three double quotes youu use, s so try it again please

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your connection driver is not configured to accept line breaks `\n`, try change your template string using concatenation or all inline statement...

```
    sql_cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    
    sql_cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO user_data (make,model,trim,fuel_type,transmission,condition,body_type,region,descriptn,eng_capacity,year,mileage, estm_value) VALUES (new_info['make'],new_info['model'],new_info['trim'],new_info['fuel_type'],new_info['transmission'],new_info['condition'],add_bodytype['body_type'],add_region['region'],new_data['description'],new_data['eng_capacity'],year,new_data['mileage'], estm_value);""")
        
    mysql.connection.commit()
    sql_cursor.close()
```

Comment: Thanks alan but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Hummm... you can put the new error here, should be out new error description, not same

Comment: MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'usage,body_type,region,descriptn,eng_capacity,year_man,mileage, estm_value) VALU' at line 1") This is the new error